# how to assign edit text value in spinner select value for specific item inspinner

Tags: android

i make a spinner in which i impliment when a select a specific item from spinner then edit text is visible other wise invisible.here all is fine
but there is a problem i want when user choose specific item then value of edit text is store in variable otherwise sppiner item value store means if user select "OTH-Other" then edit text value store in spinnerSelectedID otherwise move in else.
my elese part work nice but in if part i could not store the edit text value in spinnerSelectedID varible.

```
           ArrayList<String> faulttypespinner = new ArrayList<String>();
         faulttypespinner.add("XL-Cross Level");
         faulttypespinner.add("AL-Alignment");
         faulttypespinner.add("UN-Unevenness");
         faulttypespinner.add("XL-Cross Level");
         faulttypespinner.add("AL-Alignment");
         faulttypespinner.add("UN-Unevenness");
         faulttypespinner.add("BD-Ballast Deficiency");
         faulttypespinner.add("SE-Super elevation on curve");
         faulttypespinner.add("LP-Loose Packing");
         faulttypespinner.add("LJ-Low Joint");
         faulttypespinner.add("BA-Bridge");
         faulttypespinner.add("LC-Level Crossing");
         faulttypespinner.add("LJ-Low Joint");
         faulttypespinner.add("P and C-Point n Xing");
         faulttypespinner.add("OTH-Other");
         faulttypespinner.add("SEJ-SEJ");
         faulttypespinner.add("WEED-Weed on Cess");

      ArrayAdapter<String> faultadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (mConetxt,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, faulttypespinner);


    faultadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         mspinner.setAdapter(faultadapter);

       mspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
       int pos, long id) {
      Log.d("TESTING", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());

      if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("OTH-Other")) {


           otherdefect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           text = otherdefect.getText().toString();
         spinnerSelectedID = String.valueOf(mspinner.getSelectedItem());
           spinnerSelectedID = (otherdefect.getText().toString());

            } 
                    else  
                    {

                otherdefect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               spinnerSelectedID = String.valueOf(mspinner.getSelectedItem());

                    }



                }
```

Comment: I didn't get your question clearly, can you explain bit more what exactly you are trying.

Comment: is condition of if  "parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("OTH-Other")" really passed?

Comment: innocentkiller sir i want store edit text value in spinnerSelectedID

Comment: Sir i want if my code in if condition then the edit text value store in spinnerSelectedID ,and if user in else conditin then in spinnerSelectedID  store selected item value from sppiner